# Div is not floating left

Tags: html, css, web

I'm still relatively new to html and css, and I'm not able to figure this out. I have three divs with some text and I want them to be next to each other. I set them to float: left but they are not doing so.

```css
.threethings {
  width: 20%;
}
.threethings div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="threethings">
  <div><span>Style</span>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius te ullum indoctum, sanctus consequat eum te. Nemore recteque necessitatibus et eos.</p>
  </div>
  <div><span>Style</span>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius te ullum indoctum, sanctus consequat eum te. Nemore recteque necessitatibus et eos.</p>
  </div>
  <div><span>Style</span>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius te ullum indoctum, sanctus consequat eum te. Nemore recteque necessitatibus et eos.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
        .threethings {
            width : 100%;
        }

        .threethings div {
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            float : left;
        }
```

so what happens is divs are floated in your case but not side by side as you are giving 20% width to parent , due which children cant fload side by side.

what i did was give parent some large width and children some small width, so that parent can accomodate children floating side by side.

well as div is block. `width:100%` might not be necessary

Comment: Thanks ! How would I go about centering these horizontally on the page? I tried adding a 0 auto margin but it did not do anything.

Comment: well , i will ask you to research on it a bit. If you dont find a solution , please comment back, i am happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You're floating the parent class - not the divs containing paragraphs. Add the .threethings class to the 3 nested divs to instruct them to float their proceeding divs up alongside them.

Note that you may also need to give the divs a fixed width, as the paragraphs you have on there may exceed the length of your html body, which in turn would force them onto a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
 .threethings {
       width:100%; 
    }
    .threethings div {
        width:33%; 
        position: relative;
        float : left;
    }
```